# How to keep connection string secured in open source?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API project. My current working environment is Ubuntu. I am using a remote database. Now the problem is:

- I have to keep my project in open source repository
- I have to use the remotely connected database, so that my team-mate gets access to the APIs in Mobile Environments directly from the **deployed site** **(heroku/azure)**

But in such case, I guess this is not standard and most importantly **not secured**. So, How do I manage to secure the connection string of my remote database secured in an open source repository?

Comment: Do not publish secret informations at all. Have a look at UserSecrets (yes, it is from MS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "UserSecretManager" to put the connectionString into "secrets.json" instead of "appsetting.json". The "secrets.json" remains on your local machine and is outside of the git repository folder.

Comment: That means, I have to put that in .gitignore? But how would Azure know the secrets then?

Comment: @ShunjidRahman No, ".gitignore " includes files and folder in the git repository but you wanna ignore them. But using "UserSecret" you put the secrets outside the repository folder. Therefore, you should set a path for it. take a look at this: https://nvisium.com/blog/2019/05/02/Dev-Secrets-and-the-ASP-NET-Core-Secret-Manager.html

Comment: The secrets.json file ends up somewhere in your documents folder. If you right click the project to manage user secrets, and THEN click the project file to look at it, you will see that there is a section up top named "Secrets" with a big GUID next to it. This GUID is the folder name of your secrets.json file.

If you have multiple projects in the solution but want to keep the same secrets file, then you add that GUID to your other projectss, they will all point to the same. 

This secrets file is far away from your source code and will never be committed